# Как отследить закрытия модального окна bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Как отследить закрытия модального окна bootstrap по клику на затемненную область вне самого окна?

Answer (score 3):

Нашел парвильное решение

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addNewUser").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
       alert('The modal is about to be hidden!');
    });

});
```